# Is “agone” still a current dialectal expression?

Tags: dialects, archaicisms, british-english

***[Agone](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/agone)*** is defined in dictionaries as an archaic form of "gone" (TFD)

but according to Etymonline the term is still used as a dialectal variant:

***[Ago](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=agone):***

> - ago (adj.) 
>     early 14c., shortened form of Old English agan, agone "departed, passed away," ***past participle of an obsolete verb ago*** "to go forth," formed from a- "away"  ***Agone remains a dialectal variant.***

I presume that it refers to some regional dialect in the UK.

Questions:

1. Is the term commonly used within the UK? Which region of Great Britain is one most likely to come across this term?
2. Is *agone* heard or used  outside the UK?

Comment: As far as American English usage, no. If it is used here, it's extremely uncommon.

Comment: Agone, something that has gone by, has become ago, as in ten years ago, which actually means ten years are agone, have passed by since now.

Comment: Well change the title, that is what I understood by the tags, and your questioning about it being used in the UK or outside. The question was unclear. I think Etymonline made a mistake, the term is simply archaic, I've never heard anyone say *agone* aloud. You read it in poetry, and maybe in Victorian novels. Why are you curious about this word? What made you look it up? I'd add some context to the question. EDIT: The *just* in the title is asking whether it is true or not.

Comment: Etymonline often "copies" directly the OED, it could well be that Oxford entry has not been updated in a long time... maybe it was current at the time of printing.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Could be, but it could also be that in some regions of the UK it has remained just as a dialectal expression...I hoped for some local confirmation.

Comment: You're basing a question on a single entry, is there any outside evidence that might suggest this usage is current somewhere among the British Isles? I presume you checked Ngrams, and Google News and blogs etc. Again, what is the motivation behind your request? Do you want to use it, are you afraid it won't be understood?

Comment: @Mari-LouA - well, the source is a very reliable one and the sentence is very specific, why should I think it is not   correct. It makes sense to me, there are terms that survive in local speeches after disappearing from the national languages.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - the fact you don't like the question does not mean it is not a valid one.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - one possible answer is:  ***NO*** the expression is not used in any dialect .

Comment: *"Why should I think it is not correct?"* because no one has confirmed it, because no other dictionary says it is currently in use, because Bookeater confirms it is never very common... anything else? ODO [*Now archaic and poetic*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/agone). My point being that Ety probably made a mistake, that is plausible. And I supplied a plausible reason for that "mistake" an outdated OED entry.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - Yes it is plausible, and I personally think it is an interesing point.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. While never very common, and slightly more used in British English than American English "Agone" hit its peak around 1900.
It is still used a bit [today](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=agone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cagone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bagone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BAgone%3B%2Cc0).

Reference;
https://books.google.com/ngrams/

Comment: My question actually is about ***where***  this  "dialectal variance" is , if it still is, used.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify that? The question title does not mention "where" - it asks "if", and this is a reasonable answer to that. Even the body of your question doesn't explicitly ask "where", so I can see why @Bookeater interpreted it as written.

Comment: @RJHunter - in the body, where I ask the questions, it is clearly specified what I am asking.

Comment: Sorry Josh61, evidence points at no particular location. This of course does not disprove there is none. I reasoned part of the answer is better than none.

Comment: @Bookeater - ok thanks, my impression is that if it is still used, it is probably more in the spoken language rather than in writing. So probably some "local" user might help.

Comment: Time will tell. Hopefully.